# In gnuplot, the letters and lines of the legend are misaligned

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot.
The letters and lines of the legend are misaligned in my output figure of gnuplot.

[image]

I used the code below.

```
gnuplot -persist <<EOF
set size ratio 3/4

set tics font "Arial, 15"

set xrange [494:506]
set yrange [0:1]

set xlabel 'wavelenth [nm]' font "Arial, 20"
set ylabel 'probability' font "Arial, 20" offset -2,0

set lmargin 10
set bmargin 6
set rmargin 25

set key font "Arial, 15" outside  spacing 1.5

plot 'result.out' using 1:2 with lines title "transmittance"
replot 'result.out' using 1:3 with lines title "reflectance" lc rgb "dark-    green"
replot 'result.out' using 1:4 with lines title "absorbance"

set terminal png
set output 'out.png'
replot
EOF
```

Comment: Related: [General misalignment in Gnuplot graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163311/general-misalignment-in-gnuplot-graph)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean vertical alignment, it can be fixed using `set terminal pngcairo` instead of `set terminal png`

[image: Legend obtained with pngcairo]

Horizontal alignment can be changed in legend options, e.g. `set key font "Arial, 15" outside  spacing 1.5 Left`

[image]

Comment: Personal experience: Besides the problem described here, I alwayshad better rendering with `pngcairo` instead of `png` terminal.