# Gnuplot: Vertical misalignment key box and key label

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following gnuplot script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set terminal pdfcairo font "Latin-Modern-Roman-Bold,25" size 5,3
set output "tmp.pdf"

set tmargin 2.0
set bmargin 1.2

set offset -0.3,-0.3,0,0

set ylabel "X-Axis" offset 2,0

set xtics out nomirror offset 0,0.65 #rotate out nomirror

set yrange [0:1]
set ytics .2,.2,3 nomirror

# Select histogram data
set style data histogram
set style fill solid 1 border lt -1

set key reverse at 6.5,1.22 horizontal width 0.5 sample 2

set style line 3 lt -1 lc rgb 'yellow';
set style line 2 lt -1 lc rgb 'red';
set style line 4 lt -1 lc rgb '#008080';
set style line 5 lt -1 lc rgb 'orange';

set style histogram gap 1

plot 'tmp.tsv' using 2:xtic(1) title "AA    " ls 2, \
     'tmp.tsv' using 3:xtic(1) title "BB    " ls 3, \
     'tmp.tsv' using 4:xtic(1) title "CC    " ls 4, \
     'tmp.tsv' using 5:xtic(1) title "DD    " ls 5, \
     'tmp.tsv' using 6:xtic(1) title "EE    " ls 6, \
     'tmp.tsv' using 7:xtic(1) title "FF    " ls 7
```

This code produces the following output:

[image]

Why are the key labels (i.e., AA, BB, CC, etc.) slightly lower than their respective boxes?

Comment: gnuplot's method to align text with graphic elements isn't perfect, See [In gnuplot, the letters and lines of the legend are misaligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906834/in-gnuplot-the-letters-and-lines-of-the-legend-are-misaligned/51926495#51926495) or [General misalignment in Gnuplot graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163311/general-misalignment-in-gnuplot-graph). You could try a different font or a different terminal.

Comment: Make sure you use the latest version of gnuplot, as there may be some fixes for this.